# connecting PowerShell to SharePoint 365 online

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint 365 online through PowerShell and I keep getting this error:[image]

this is what I entered, I need to be able to write scripts on SharePoint.

```
$adminUPN="***@***.com"
$orgName="****"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "*******"
Connect-SPOService -Url https://******** -Credential $userCredential
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you get started using PowerShell to manage SharePoint Online, make sure that the SharePoint Online Management Shell is installed.
Install the SharePoint Online Management Shell by downloading and running the [SharePoint Online Management Shell](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=255251) setup. To open the SharePoint Online Management Shell command prompt, from the Start screen, type sharepoint, and then click SharePoint Online Management Shell.

Answer (score 0):

For improving your productivity with SharePoint Online PowerShell scripts use: [SharePointPnP.PowerShel](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell)

**Install:**

If you main OS is Windows 10, or if you have [PowerShellGet](https://github.com/powershell/powershellget) installed, you can run the following commands to install the PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
```

**Usage:**

Connect:

```
Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://yoursite.sharepoint.com –Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

Create list:

```
New-PnPList -Title "Demo List" -Url "DemoList" -Template Announcements
```

**Commands Documentation**

[All commands documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/readme.md)